# Copying multiple rows from a list of XLSX files and pasting them by transposition into one destination XLSX file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple rows from a list of XLSX source files into one destination XLSX file. I am having trouble copying data from more than one row at a time, and transposing the copied data properly in the destination file, since the data of interest in the source files is displayed as rows, and the data in the destination file must be displayed as columns.

The process is the following:

1. For each XLSX source file, copy non-empty data from the following rows: 5, 6, 209, 213, 214, 215 and 352; starting at column H (so seven rows of non-empty data)
2. Paste the copied data from each source file into columns W, X, Z, AA, AB, AC and AD in the destination file by transposition. For each column in the destination file, the data copied must be copied at the correct address, that is, the used range address of each row in 1) + 1.

I am using the following macro created by the user "omegastripes" to accomplish this task:

```
Sub copypaste()
strPathSrc = "C:\test" ' Source files folder
strMaskSrc = "*.xlsx" ' Source files filter mask
iSheetSrc = 1 ' Sourse sheet index or name
strPathDst = "C:\test\Results\Results.xlsx" ' Destination file
iSheetDst = 1 ' Destination sheet index or name

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkBookDst = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathDst)
Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Sheets(iSheetDst)
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShellApp.NameSpace(strPathSrc)
Set objItems = objFolder.Items()
objItems.Filter 64 + 128, strMaskSrc
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each objItem In objItems
    Set objWorkBookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objItem.Path)
    Set objSheetSrc = objWorkBookSrc.Sheets(iSheetSrc)
    GetUsedRange(objSheetSrc).Copy
    Set objUsedRangeDst = GetUsedRange(objSheetDst)
    iRowsCount = objUsedRangeDst.Rows.Count
    objWorkBookDst.Activate
    objSheetDst.Cells(iRowsCount + 1, 1).Select
    objSheetDst.Paste
    objWorkBookDst.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    objWorkBookSrc.Close
Next
End Sub

Function GetUsedRange(objSheet)
    With objSheet
        Set GetUsedRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1))
    End With
End Function
```

This module works as intended when copying content from the first cell of a worksheet to the destination file. Could someone please point my in the right direction as to how I can correct the macro above to select the rows containing the data I want in step 1) of my process, then copy these rows and transpose them correctly to the columns in step 2) of my destination file?

I am not a programmer so have very limited programming knowledge. I could not find answers on this site regarding the transposition of copied cells from a source file to a destination file when multiple source rows are selected.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Instead of `objSheetDst.Paste`, try `objSheetDst.Cells(...).PasteSpecial(Transpose:=True)`. I put `...` because you'll also have to flip the `iRowsCount` stuff into columns or something. I don't know what your sheet looks like. Main idea is to use [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) instead of Worksheet.Paste

Comment: My best guess would be something like `iRowsCount = objUsedRangeDst.Columns.Count` and then use `Cells(1, iRowsCount + 1)` in my comment above. Although at this point `iRowsCount` should be renamed something like `iColsCount` for clarity and readability.

Comment: Thank you. I've made the changes you mentionned, but how do I tell the module to select only the row addresses I mentionned in my original post? (H5, H6, H209, H213, H214, H215, H352)

Comment: You'd have to change `GetUsedRange(objSheetSrc).Copy` into something like `objSheetSrc.Range("H5, H6, H209, H213, H214, H215, H352").EntireRow.Copy` but if you want only non-blank rows, you'll need to test each one of those rows and build the range row by row. like `For Each RowRange in objSheetSrc.Range("H5, H6, H209, H213, H214, H215, H352").EntireRow.Rows` and test `With RowRange.Cells(RowRange.Cells.Count).End(xlToLeft): If Not (.Column = 1 And .Value = "") Then `

Comment: Could you please provide a full module with these code additions? If you don't mind.

Comment: I won't. The question you posted was "Could someone please point me in the right direction?". I am unable to post an answer that directly tackles the question because the question is too vague. Other than that, I've already given enough advice for you to complete the project on your own. If you run into difficulty while writing the project, post another question detailing your new troubles.

Comment: You posted code with no indication as to where it should go in the module. As a non-programmer, I find it hard to know where in my module I must place the code. Could you please just point out where I must place the code. Thank you.